# How can I make a basic Servlet using interface "Servlet"?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am running Tomcat v7.0. I am trying to learn Servlets. I have tried to use the following code:

I tried to correct the called URL. Then I deleted my project and made a new one. But the error remains the same, "Http 404". How can I correct the called URL or make a Servlet using "Servlet" interface?[Either the called URL is wrong or maybe the code is wrong!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rv5T.jpg)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet("/Hello2")
public class Hello2 implements Servlet {
    ServletConfig config = null;

    public Hello2() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Servlet is destroyed!");
    }
    @Override
    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        return config;
    }
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Copyright 2017-2018";
    }
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        this.config = config;
        System.out.println("Servlet is initialized!");
    }
    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>");
        out.println("Hello2");
        out.println("</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h2>Hello Hello!!</h2>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        out.close();
    }
}
```

I tried to change the calling URL using web.xml
This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SDM</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SDM</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You have to call `http://localhost:8080/SDM/Hello2` - that's the path defined by `@WebServlet("/Hello2")`. Btw. using the [HttpServlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) is usually a much better idea than directly `Servlet`.

Comment: Try localhost:8080/yourwebappid/Hello2

Comment: Yeah, I know I have already tried that using `HttpServlet` class. But I was trying to learn it by `Servlet` interface. Can you please explain me? I am new to Servlets.